# What is the use of "@" in java .properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a version. properties file in spring boot application, it has the following lines,

```
buildverions=@buildverions
gitcommit=@gitcommit
```

what is the use of the symbol "`@`" in the above scenario, java .properties file

Comment: None. The properties file seems to be pre-processed during the build, right?

Comment: i think so. i am trying to understand the codebase, I thought `@` has symatic meaning

Comment: I use a similar approach in one of my projects, but a similar properties file from the resource directory is [filtered](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) using Apache Maven (e.g., `app.version=${project.version}`).

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's `@gitcommit@` rather than what's in the post.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- No, it is only `@gitcommit`

Comment: It is possible that these values are added by build tool or IDE that you are using.